# Can't delete old Mac Time Machine backups

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, mojave

I'm on 10.14 Mojave. I can't delete old backups in Time Machine with any of the suggested methods on the interwebs:

**Attempt 1**. Enter Time Machine -> click on cog -> delete backup.

Fail: "Some files can’t be processed, either because you don’t have permission to modify them, or because they are on a locked volume."

**Attempt 2**. Terminal:

```
sudo tmutil delete /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Backups.backupdb/BadassMacBook/2015-01-20-142139
```

Fail: Error (-36) deleting: /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Backups.backupdb/BadassMacBook/2015-01-20-142139
Error (642) re-linking Latest for machine directory: /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Backups.backupdb/BadassMacBook
Total deleted: 4.0K

**Attempt 3**. Bypass ["Operation not permitted"](https://superuser.com/a/387464)
Terminal:

```
sudo /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass rm -rfv /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Backups.backupdb/BadassMacBook/2015-01-20-142139
```

Fail: "Read-only file system" for every file, nothing deleted.

Where do I go from here??